# How to find random elements in XML transformation using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, xhtml, transform

I'm facing an issue while transforming XML like I can't able to fetch the elements in their correct order. Those elements are random and can't predict the order they came.

Here is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl"?>
<toc>
    <layout>
        <header>Item 1</header>
        <tocItem>item one - a</tocItem>
        <tocItem>item one - b</tocItem>
        <header>Item 2</header>
        <tocItem>item two - a</tocItem>
        <tocItem>item two - b</tocItem>
        <tocItem>item two - c</tocItem>
        <tocItem>item two - d</tocItem>
        <tocItem>item two - e</tocItem>
        <header>Item 3</header>
        <tocItem>item three - a</tocItem>
        <header>Item 4</header>
        <tocItem>item four - a</tocItem>
        <tocItem>item four - b</tocItem>
        <tocItem>item four - c</tocItem>
        <header>Item 5</header>
        <tocItem>item five - a</tocItem>
        <tocItem>item five - b</tocItem>
    </layout>
    <layout>
        <header>Item 1</header>
        <tocItem>item one - a</tocItem>
        <tocItem>item one - b</tocItem>
        <header>Item 2</header>
        <tocItem>item two - a</tocItem>  
    </layout>
    <layout>
        <header>Item 1</header>
        <tocItem>item one - a</tocItem>
        <tocItem>item one - b</tocItem>
        <tocItem>item one - c</tocItem>
        <tocItem>item one - d</tocItem>
        <tocItem>item one - e</tocItem>
        <header>Item 2</header>
        <tocItem>item two - c</tocItem>
        <tocItem>item two - d</tocItem>
        <tocItem>item two - e</tocItem>
        <header>Item 4</header>
        <tocItem>item four - a</tocItem>
        <tocItem>item four - b</tocItem>
        <header>Item 5</header>
        <tocItem>item five - a</tocItem>  
    </layout>
</toc>
```

And here goes XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:template match="/">

            <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8" />
                <title>Title</title>
            </head>

            <body>
                <div class="toc">
                    <xsl:for-each select="/toc/layout">
                    <div class="layout">                    
                        <xsl:for-each select="/toc/layout/header">
                            <div class="header">
                                <p><xsl:value-of select="header" /></p>
                            </div>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                        <xsl:for-each select="/toc/layout/tocItem">
                            <div class="tocItem">
                                <p><xsl:value-of select="tocItem" /></p>
                            </div>
                        </xsl:for-each>                    
                    </div>  
                    </xsl:for-each>              
                </div>
            </body>

            </html>
    </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I tried the above method, it is just repeating the first header element and first tocItems. And I got all the elements when trying this code `<xsl:value-of select="." />` inside the layout div. My goal is to fetch them as one by one order. Like below.

Items 1

item one - a

item one - b

Items 2

item two - a

item two - b

item two - c

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish here. The input seems to be in very precise order.  Please show the exact and full expected result in the given example and explain the logic that needs to applied in order to get it.

Comment: P.S. You have `<xsl:for-each select="/toc/layout">` within `<xsl:for-each select="/toc/layout">`. That makes no sense.

Comment: In general, if you want to just transform all those elements to HTML `div` with a `class` attribute based on the element name then one template suffices doing that; and to preserve the input order it is best or at least easiest to simply apply-templates. See https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ncdD7ne for an example. I am not sure however if you also want to wrap the items following a header or nest them, then more work might be needed.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, sorry that was my mistake. I just made an edit. Although I'm not having that much programming skills just doing it myself by following the w3 schools XML tutorial.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, this is exactly I'm looking to achieve, thank you.

Comment: @AkhilPaul, I have morphed the comment into an answer so that you can accept it and mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if you want to just transform all those elements to HTML `div` with a `class` attribute based on the element name then one template suffices doing that:

```
  <xsl:template match="toc | layout | header | tocItem">
      <div class="{local-name()}">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </div>
  </xsl:template>
```

And to preserve the input order it is best or at least easiest to simply `apply-templates`.

An example is

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="no" html-version="5"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>.NET XSLT Fiddle Example</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="toc | layout | header | tocItem">
      <div class="{local-name()}">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </div>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That uses the XSLT 3 only declaration `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` to set up the identity transformation as a default processing but in earlier versions you can simply spell that out as

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

See https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ncdD7ne to experiment with it online.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't examined what you are trying to achieve but your `xsl:for-each` is clearly wrong. When you write `<xsl:for-each select="/toc/layout">`, then the context node within the for-each is a `<layout>` element and one would expect further selections to be relative to that element, rather than absolute paths from the root of the document. I don't understand why you have two levels of `xsl:for-each` in the first place.

Comment: that was a mistake from my end. And it seems Martin Honnen's fiddle helped me. Btw thank you for replying the question.